# React CSV Downloader is downloading a blank csv file

Tags: reactjs, csv, react-hooks

I have an issue with the React CSV Downloader plugin, below:

```
export default function Component(props) {
    ...
    [data, setData] = useState([]);
    ...

    const downloadData = async () => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      
        // make request via axios
        return data;

        try{
            ...
            // do some logic to clean the data
            ...

            setData(cleanedData);
            resolve(data); // also tried resolve(cleanedData);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
          }
        });
      };

      return (
        <CsvDownload
          datas={downloadData}
          filename={"name"}
          extension=".csv"
          handleEmpty={() => void 0}
        >
            <Button>Download</Button>
        </CsvDownload>
    );
}
```

The problem is that when downloading the CSV, the first time the file downloads it's empty. Upon clicking the download button the second time, the CSV is then populated. Can anyone help shed some light on what could be going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, don't worry. Figured it out by updating to the below. Using useEffect & useRef to trigger the CSVDownloader handleClick() function only after useEffect has data available to download, before then clearing the data.

```
export default function Component(props) {
    ...
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const csvInstance = useRef(null);
    ...

    const downloadData = async () => {
      
        try{
            // make request via axios
                return data;
            ...
            // do some logic to clean the data
                return cleanedData
            ...

            setData(cleanedData);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (
            !!data &&
            data.length > 0 &&
            csvInstance &&
            csvInstance.current &&
            csvInstance.current.handleClick
        ) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                csvInstance.current.handleClick();
                setData([]); // reset data after download
            });
        }
    }, [data]);

    return (
        <CsvDownload
          datas={data}
          filename={"name"}
          extension=".csv"
          handleEmpty={() => void 0}
          ref={csvInstance}
        >
            <Button onClick={downloadData}>Download</Button>
        </CsvDownload>
    );
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone.